# Loop through stack using traditional for-loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, stack

Why doesn't this work:

I have two items on the stack, but it goes through the loop once

```
for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
            String[] values = stack.pop().trim().replaceAll(" ", "").split("/");
            String[] moveList = values[0].trim().replaceAll(" ", "").split("-");
}
```

Comment: what happens to the size when you pop one off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stack Pop loop does not pop all elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557212/stack-pop-loop-does-not-pop-all-elements)

Comment: Do you use ArrayDeque as the stack implementation?

Comment: Size decreases by 1 so I need to do <= ?

Comment: @JMadushan I just use stack, what is that?

Comment: You'd better using 'while loop' cuz after 'pop', stack length will change

Comment: Specifically, `while (!stack.isEmpty())`

Comment: Instead of checking  `<=` use `while(!stack.empty())` loop.

Comment: @Johnny "ArrayDeque" is the modern implementation for the usage for "Stack", Java recommends using that for that in modern code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using for loop you should use a while loop to iterate over all elements.

Example:

```
   while(!stack.empty()){
       String[] values = stack.pop().trim().replaceAll(" ", "").split("/");
       String[] moveList = values[0].trim().replaceAll(" ", "").split("-");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In a Stack object the `pop()` method removes the object at the top of the stack and returns the object as the result. So at the first execution, the `stack.pop()` operation removes the first item from the stack and so the size is decreased from `2` to `1`. At the next iteration of the "**for**" loop, the variable `i` has a value of `1`, and the "**for**" condition `i<stack.size()` is not verified, so the "**for**" loop is terminated. That's why it goes through the loop only once.
It would be better to check if the stack is not empty as loop condition.